# Two tables with m to n relationship

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, Puchases(**purchID**,empID*(foreignkey)*) and Item(**itemID**,itemName,unitPrice). The two tables have to have a many to many relationship. I can insert data into the two tables separately but inserting data to the table bought(**purchID,itemID**,qty) is not possible. Which SQL statement should I use?

Comment: Not quite sure how this relates to WAMPServer at all, but it sounds like you're looking for a bridging table (also known as associative entity). As for the specific statement, it depends on what you're trying to do. Insert data? Select data? etc.

Comment: What I want to know  is how to insert data into this third table?

Answer (score 0):

You need a new table:

```
CREATE TABLE Purchase_Item (
    purchID INT, -- foreign key to Purchases.purchID
    itemID INT, -- foreign key to Item.itemID
    quantity INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (purchID, itemID)
)
```